# How to download a file with a very long URL?

Tags: javascript, url, post, web, download

Basically I'm trying to trigger the download of a file which is constructed dynamically. In order to construct the file I need to pass a lot of information to the servlet.

This means I can't use GET, I should use POST instead.

In order for the download not to mess the application up, though, I must open a new window. The problem is that I cannot do this:
window.open(http://very.long.url.com/.../, "_blank");

since this would cause the URL limit to be exceeded and GET to be used instead of POST.

All information that needs to be sent to the servlet are in an object called "config.

My solution was to write a form in the new window with POST method, then add hidden inputs to it and then trigger the submit, like this:

```
var win = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
win.document.write("<form method='post' id=donwload action='serveletURL'></form>");

$.each(config, function (name, value) {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = '<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'' + name + '\' value=\'' + value + '\'></input>';
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        fragment.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }

    win.document.getElementById("download").appendChild(fragment);
});

win.document.getElementById('download').submit();
```

And it works in Google Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work on IE. On IE (even IE 10), a download dialog with a "serveletURL" file name opens and nothing gets downloaded when I ask the file to be saved or opened.

I'm sure I'm missing something... How do I accomplish this??

Thank you!
Eduardo

Comment: Specifically what is the last part (the "filetype") of the servelet's URL? I'm virtually certain this has nothing to do with either the "length" of the URL or the "POST" operation. And I'm also virtually certain your data is being packaged and uploaded okay. The problem seems to be later in the "download" part of the operation. IE is somehow triggering off either some HTTP header or the servelet filetype that this kind of file should be "downloaded" instead of "displayed". To figure out exactly what's happening, we need to know the last part of the actual URL.

Comment: There is no file type, the URL is pointing to the servlet itself, such as http://www.domain.com/projects/download/?fileId=4&...

But the query string gets really long, so I can't use window.open(); to launch this URL in a new window. Hence my attempt to use POST form. 

The server response, however, contains the proper Content-Disposition header with "attachment" value.